# Unable to connect with MySQL database with visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to configure `MySQL` database into by `dot net` application. For this, I have installed it.

1. [MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.9](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/)
2. [Connector/NET 8.0.22](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)
3. Entity Framework 6 (EF6)
4. [MySql.Data.EntityFramework](http://nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFramework) version 8.0.22 via nuget

**App.config**

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory,  MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
  </provider></providers>
```

When I am trying to add the database I am getting below error

[image]

I have tried almost every solution on the stack but nothing solves the problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a clear problem as well as the error simply says :

> The Entity Framework database provider is not compatible with this
> version of Entity Framework

As a **reference**, Consider the steps inside [connector net entityframework60](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html) **carefully** as it describes two types of .net projects (.net & .net core) for connecting to the MySQL database. In your case follow the *Minimum Requirements for EF6 on Windows Only* and Note to the .NET Framework **version** and **compatibility**.

**Be careful** about what you *referenced* and what you *installed* by comparing configuration files with assembly references in your project. I don't know how well you control the project dependencies. **If you compare the [Configuration section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html#connector-net-ef6-config) you will find out that is completely different with yours**. And there may be some more possible unwanted mistakes which we don't have control over it far from you as well as we can't reproduce the problem.

Finally, check what you have inside *assembly references* and *configuration files*. After making deep changes, you may have to restart the Visual Studio in order to track them to be confirmed or not.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message describe you have a incompatible mysql connector try to delete all and create again.
You can try from the source directly @ [the mysql source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html#connector-net-ef6-requirements)

try to change your config to

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        connectionString="server=yourserver;port=3306;database=mycontext;uid=root;password=********    "/>
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory     type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
<providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework"/>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,     EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
</providers>
</entityFramework>
```

after add the mysql package `MySql.Data.EntityFramework` you can add from:

1. the package manager `Install-Package MySql.Data.EntityFramework -Version 8.0.22`
2. command line `dotnet add package MySql.Data.EntityFramework -Version 8.0.22`
3. within visual studio nuget package manager

you can continue discover the [the mysql source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html#connector-net-ef6-requirements) there is a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you are using a provider that incompatible. The root cause is likely that you have duplicate `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` providers, one loading from the `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6` assembly and the other loading from the `MySql.Data.EntityFramework` assembly.

```
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
    type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />

...
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
```

Per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html) your entity framework section should look like this.

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
            type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework"/>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
            type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Additionally it appears your default connection factory is using the wrong assembly and type:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory 
    type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
```

The documentation shows `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory` from the EntityFramework assembly should be used instead:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory 
    type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
```

Also, register the `DbProviderFactories`

```
<configuration>
    <system.data>
       <DbProviderFactories>
         <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
         <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
            type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=8.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
       </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
<configuration>
```

Note to always update the version number to match the one in the MySql.Data.dll assembly you are using.